# How to find P pins to cover K points in 2D array?

Tags: algorithm

I need to find the minimum number of pinsneeded to place on an N-by-M rectangular grid (N horizontal line segments and M vertical line segments) to enclose at least K intersection points. An intersection point is enclosed if either of the following conditions is true:

1. A pin is placed at the point.
2. Starting from the point, we cannot trace a path along grid lines to reach an empty point on the grid border through empty intersection points only.

For example, to enclose 8 points on a 4x5 grid, we need at least 6 pins. One of many valid pin layouts is

[image]

Enclosed points are marked with an "x".

I've thought over the problem but I cant seem to find a solution. Could any of you please help?

Comment: How large are N, M, K?

Comment: N × M <= 1000.
K <= N x M

Comment: Interesting question then. There are some obvious polynomial-time DP approaches but they don't even come close to linear time.

Comment: What are the polynomial time DP approaches? I am not able to figure out any way to do this.

Comment: @JackRyan Note that the hull will always be convex. I'm thinking about a state like (row, left border, right border, total length of border). This yields an O(N*M^2*(N+M)) algorithm, far from viable for your scale of input.

Comment: Suppose in my input N x M <= 20. How would I solve it now?

Comment: @JackRyan Well then you can easily use the DP approach I just described. It's cumbersome to implement the transitions though.

Comment: Also, I don't have to give the layout I will follow. Just the minimum number of pins required.

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Comment: @JackRyan In all likelihood that does not make it any simpler

Comment: I think optimal location of pins is always close to a square formed by diagonals of the grid and centered near the center of the grid (possibly with 2 or 4 corners "cut off" by borders of the grid). This allows O(1) algorithm.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev I can certainly imagine cases where it's better to have a single chain of pins, for example, or a combination of multiple rectangles, or rectangles with chains etc. And O(1)? What?

Comment: I'm just noticing an unclarity of the statement. Can we have multiple distinct enclosed components or do all the nodes need to be enclosed in the same "polygon" of pins?

Comment: @NiklasB.: It seems our understanding of the problem is not equal. I assumed all M*N grid points equal. Possibly you assume K points as given separately?

Comment: @Evgeny I see, if every intersection is a candidate point, then indeed your approach  seems correct.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3t5dr/) legal? x is an enclosed point, 0 is a pin with an enclosed point under it, + is empty grid point.

Comment: The paper ["Finding Minimum Area k-gons"](http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/papers/area-k-gons.pdf) solves this in *O(kn^3)* time, where *k* is the size of the subset and *n* is the number of candidate points. Specifically you want Collary 5.3 & Theorem 5.2, which generalizes the result to the minimum perimeter problem. e: Just seen Niklas's performance worries. Yeah a possibly quartic algorithm could get ugly with a 1000 point input.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the input? Is it just numbers n, m, k? Or do you have a list of points as a part of the input where only points in that list are counted towards k?

Comment: Of it is just n, m, and k then it is simply a case analysis and the running time will be O(1) (i.e. does not depend on n, m, and k).

Comment: For the record: **This question was an attempt to cheat!!** The problem came from **Google CodeJam 2014**, and solutions are made available on the official website after each contest.